# Fill squares in Sudoku board using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to create a program that reads a sudoku board from a txt file and finds possible solution(s) to the board.
I've created objects of each square and added them to a 2d-array:
(This board have 28 different solutions)

```
001003
000000
000020
260000
000300
300102
```

I have successfully added the squares to corresponding column, row and box. But I'm having trouble with my recursive method that tries to find possible solution(s) of the board and add each solutions to a container in a different class that uses nodes to keep track of all the solutions. The method in my container class should take Square[][] squares as parameters.

I start the recursive method off with:

```
squares[0][0].fillInRemainingOfBoard();
```

from another class called Board.

My recursive method that is supposed to check all the squares looks like this:

```
protected void fillInRemainingOfBoard() {
    // If Square is not '0' in the txt file it goes in here
    if(this instanceof SquareDone) {
        // If next != null it goes in here.
        if(next != null) {
            next.fillInRemainingOfBoard();
        }

    // If the square is empty it goes in here
    } else if(this instanceof SquareEmpty) {
        if(next != null) {
            // Searching for possible numbers for square
            // Rows, Column and Box have the same length; 
            //thats why row.getLength() in for-loop
            for(int i=1; i<=row.getLength(); i++) {

            // Set new value to square if this is true,
            // then move on to next square
                if(row.getLegal(i) && column.getLegal(i) && box.getLegal(i)) {
                    setNewValue(i);
                    next.fillInRemainingOfBoard();
                }
            }
        } else  {
            for(int i=1; i<=row.get(); i++) {
                if(row.getLegal(i) && column.getLegal(i) && box.getLegal(i)) {
                    setNewValue(i);
              // No next.fillInRemainingOfBoard() here because it's the last square
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a super-class for the rows, columns and boxes which holds the variables and methods for the subclasses. The method that checks for legal values looks like this:

```
public boolean getLegal(int square) {
    for(int i=0; i<rkb.length; i++) {
        if(rute == rkb[i].getVerdi()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

My output of this looks like this

```
4 2 1 5 6 3
5 3 6 2 1 4
1 4 3 6 2 5
2 6 5 4 3 1
6 1 4 3 5 0
3 0 0 1 0 2
```

So my question is: Why is my code not adding values to each square and how can I save a solution and send them to another class, then start over and check for more solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why its not adding value to each square, is because the algorithm is incorrect. As you can see from position [5][4] of your array, value by line 2 and value by column should be 6. Meaning the algorithm messed up previous values and cannot find further ones.

I suspect this happens because in part of your code bellow, setNewValue(i) is set for the last solution found, but the if statement may find multiple solutions in the beginning of the program, as not many squares are filled, and not always the last solution is the good one.

```
if(next != null) {
        for(int i=1; i<=row.getLength(); i++) {
            if(row.getLegal(i) && column.getLegal(i) && box.getLegal(i)) {
                setNewValue(i);
                next.fillInRemainingOfBoard();
            }
}
```

To solve this, you should store all values that match the if statement and figure out how to use them later. (maybe skip the current cell if it has more then 1 solution and come back to it later)

This is just my hypothesis, but you can use a debugger to see if this is truly the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast implementation of Sudoku Solver which I implemented a couple of years back.
https://gist.github.com/dapurv5/e636c85a5a85cd848ca2

You might want to read about Minimum Remaining Value heuristic. This is one of the standard ways to solve a CSP (Constraint Satisfaction Problem)